# Blob Index Tag feature not enabled in my Azure Blob Storage (Block Premium)

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

When uploading a file to my `Azure Blob Storage` instance, I don't see the interface to set the blob index tags, which leads me to think that `Blob Index Tags` feature is not enabled in my storage account.

I have a block Premium account and hierarchical namespaces are not enabled. In addition, I granted my user the role of `Storage Blob Data Owner`.

Is there any other step I need to take?

Comment: How are you uploading?

Comment: For testing purposes I'm uploading from the Azure Portal directly.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got to know below results:

In general v2 accounts you will find Blob Index Tags while uploading Blobs as below:

[image]

But when I created a Premium Storage account, there is no Blob index tagging because In Premium **page and legacy**  blobs indexing is not possible as below:

[image]

As [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-find-blobs?tabs=azure-portal#conditions-and-known-issues) the known limitation for Premium and Block blob Premium also is not supported from Portal to do blob indexing. I tried to add Blob index tags from Storage Explorer but tags were not visible in premium and page as this is a limitation(In [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-find-blobs?tabs=azure-portal#conditions-and-known-issues) it says, we can only get to know about page is not possible , but i have tried with Block and its not possible too).